# Найти последнюю строку в каждой группе из 2 строк

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть пример таблицы

```sql
select *
from ( values
    (1,15,'stage_1'),
    (12,15,'stage_11'),
    (13,15,'stage_11'),
    (28,15,'stage_3'),
    (30,15,'stage_11'),
    (35,15,'stage_3'),

    (77,23,'stage_1'),
    (98,23,'stage_3'),
    (101,23,'stage_4'),

    (1021,34,'stage_1'),
    (1031,34,'stage_11'),
    (1035,34,'stage_11'),
    (1039,34,'stage_11'),
    (1059,34,'stage_11'),
    (1021,34,'stage_9'),

    (21506,89,'stage_17'),
    (21521,89,'stage_2'),
    (21543,89,'stage_11'),
    (21568,89,'stage_8'),

    (2221,314,'stage_1'),
    (2311,314,'stage_11'),
    (2352,314,'stage_11'),
    (2355,314,'stage_11')
) as stages(id, number, stage)
```

Необходимо найти (пометить) последний **stage_11** в каждой группе из 2, а также все элементы, которые не имеют группы. Группой из 2 считаются только 2 следующих друг за другом **stage_11** в группе по полю *number* с сортировкой по *id*, *number*. Групп может быть несколько.

```sql
|-------ИСХОДНИК--------|            |--------ЧТО ТРЕБУЕТСЯ--------|
|id    |number|stage    |            |id    |number|stage    |cnt  |
|------|------|---------|            |------|------|---------|-----|
|1     |15    |stage_1  |            |1     |15    |stage_1  |NULL |
|12    |15    |stage_11 |            |12    |15    |stage_11 |NULL |
|13    |15    |stage_11 |            |13    |15    |stage_11 |1    | -- последний id из (12,13)
|28    |15    |stage_3  |            |28    |15    |stage_3  |NULL |
|30    |15    |stage_11 |            |30    |15    |stage_11 |1    | -- нет пары
|35    |15    |stage_3  |            |35    |15    |stage_3  |NULL |
|------|------|---------|            |------|------|---------|-----|
|77    |23    |stage_1  |            |77    |23    |stage_1  |NULL |
|98    |23    |stage_3  |            |98    |23    |stage_3  |NULL |
|101   |23    |stage_4  |            |101   |23    |stage_4  |NULL |
|------|------|---------|            |------|------|---------|-----|
|1021  |34    |stage_1  |            |1021  |34    |stage_1  |NULL |
|1021  |34    |stage_9  |            |1021  |34    |stage_9  |NULL |
|1031  |34    |stage_11 |            |1031  |34    |stage_11 |NULL |
|1035  |34    |stage_11 |            |1035  |34    |stage_11 |1    | -- последний id из (1031,1035)
|1039  |34    |stage_11 |            |1039  |34    |stage_11 |NULL |
|1059  |34    |stage_11 |            |1059  |34    |stage_11 |1    | -- последний id из (1039,1059)
|------|------|---------|            |------|------|---------|-----|
|21506 |89    |stage_17 |            |21506 |89    |stage_17 |NULL |
|21521 |89    |stage_2  |            |21521 |89    |stage_2  |NULL |
|21543 |89    |stage_11 |            |21543 |89    |stage_11 |1    | -- нет пары
|21568 |89    |stage_8  |            |21568 |89    |stage_8  |NULL |
|------|------|---------|            |------|------|---------|-----|
|2221  |314   |stage_1  |            |2221  |314   |stage_1  |NULL |
|2311  |314   |stage_11 |            |2311  |314   |stage_11 |NULL |
|2352  |314   |stage_11 |            |2352  |314   |stage_11 |1    | -- последний id из (2311,2352)
|2355  |314   |stage_11 |            |2355  |314   |stage_11 |1    | -- нет пары
```

Пробовал сделать через `row_number()` + `left join`, а также `lag()` и `lead()`, но ничего не вышло. Когда всего одна пара и одна без пары, то норм, но когда появляется 2 и более пар, то все ломается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH cte1 AS (
  SELECT *, 
         CASE WHEN stage = 'stage_11'
              THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY number ORDER BY stage, id) 
              END rn1, 
         CASE WHEN stage = 'stage_11'
              THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY number ORDER BY id) 
              END rn2
  FROM stages
),
cte2 AS (
  SELECT *, 
         CASE WHEN stage = 'stage_11'
              THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY number, rn2-rn1 ORDER BY id) 
              END rngrp
  FROM cte1
)
SELECT id, number, stage, -- *,
       CASE WHEN rngrp IS NULL
                THEN NULL
            WHEN rngrp % 2 = 0
                THEN 1
            WHEN LEAD(rngrp) OVER (PARTITION BY number ORDER BY id) IS NULL
                THEN 1
            END cnt
FROM cte2
ORDER BY 2,1
```

| id | number | stage | cnt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 15 | stage_1 | *null* |
| 12 | 15 | stage_11 | *null* |
| 13 | 15 | stage_11 | 1 |
| 28 | 15 | stage_3 | *null* |
| 30 | 15 | stage_11 | 1 |
| 35 | 15 | stage_3 | *null* |
| 77 | 23 | stage_1 | *null* |
| 98 | 23 | stage_3 | *null* |
| 101 | 23 | stage_4 | *null* |
| 1021 | 34 | stage_1 | *null* |
| 1021 | 34 | stage_9 | *null* |
| 1031 | 34 | stage_11 | 1 |
| 1035 | 34 | stage_1 | *null* |
| 1039 | 34 | stage_11 | *null* |
| 1059 | 34 | stage_11 | 1 |
| 21506 | 89 | stage_17 | *null* |
| 21521 | 89 | stage_2 | *null* |
| 21543 | 89 | stage_11 | 1 |
| 21568 | 89 | stage_8 | *null* |
| 2221 | 314 | stage_1 | *null* |
| 2311 | 314 | stage_11 | *null* |
| 2352 | 314 | stage_11 | 1 |
| 2355 | 314 | stage_11 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6ICVBpoW)

Comment: Не корректно отрабатывает в случае:
```sql

select *
from ( values
    (1021,34,'stage_1'),
    (1031,34,'stage_11'),
 (1032,34,'stage_1'),
    (1039,34,'stage_11'),
    (1059,34,'stage_11'),
    (1021,34,'stage_9')

) as stages(id, number, stage)
```

Comment: @maksimski Лучше выкладывайте линк на fiddle с проблемой. И делайте статическую таблицу (как в моём fiddle), а не from values.

Comment: Буду иметь ввиду))

Вот - https://dbfiddle.uk/H6RGN7L5

Comment: @maksimski Вроде поправил.. проверьте на всех возможных сочетаниях.

Comment: Спасибо, проверю обязательно)

Answer (score 0):

Сделал такое себе решение

```sql
    if object_id('tempdb..#tmp_values') is not null drop table #tmp_values
    select *
    into #tmp_values
    from ( values
        (1,15,'stage_1'),
        (12,15,'stage_11'),
        (13,15,'stage_11'),
        (28,15,'stage_3'),
        (30,15,'stage_11'),
        (35,15,'stage_3'),

        (77,23,'stage_1'),
        (98,23,'stage_3'),
        (101,23,'stage_4'),

        (1021,34,'stage_1'),
        (1031,34,'stage_11'),
        (1035,34,'stage_11'),
        (1039,34,'stage_11'),
        (1059,34,'stage_11'),
        (1021,34,'stage_9'),

        (21506,89,'stage_17'),
        (21521,89,'stage_2'),
        (21543,89,'stage_11'),
        (21568,89,'stage_8'),

        (2221,314,'stage_1'),
        (2311,314,'stage_11'),
        (2352,314,'stage_11'),
        (2355,314,'stage_11')
    ) as stages(id, number, stage)

    if object_id('tempdb..#tmp_reassigment') is not null drop table #tmp_reassigment
    select id, number, stage
    into #tmp_reassigment
    from #tmp_values


    if object_id('tempdb..#tmp_stages') is not null drop table #tmp_stages
    select *
    into #tmp_stages
    from #tmp_reassigment
    where 1=0

    DECLARE @id int
        , @number int
        , @stage varchar(50)
        , @id_next int
        , @number_next int
        , @stage_next varchar(50)

    DECLARE stages_cur CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT id, number, stage FROM #tmp_reassigment

    OPEN stages_cur
    FETCH NEXT FROM stages_cur INTO @id, @number, @stage
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

        FETCH NEXT FROM stages_cur INTO @id_next, @number_next, @stage_next

        IF @stage = 'stage_11' and @stage_next = 'stage_11'
        BEGIN
            insert into #tmp_stages(id, number, stage)
            select @id_next, @number_next, @stage_next

            FETCH NEXT FROM stages_cur INTO @id_next, @number_next, @stage_next
        END ELSE IF @stage = 'stage_11' BEGIN
            insert into #tmp_stages(id, number, stage)
            select @id, @number, @stage
        END

        select @id = @id_next, @number = @number_next, @stage = @stage_next

    END

    CLOSE stages_cur
    DEALLOCATE stages_cur


    select * from #tmp_stages
```